# Laravel: change database content in migration

Tags: laravel, eloquent, migration

In one of tables I have a column named `state` of the type integer. In my app I'm mapping those integers to different states, for example *canceled*.

Now I want to refactor this part of my app and I'd like to use a string representation of the state in my database. So instead of the integer **5** I want to save the string **'canceled'**.

Within a migration, is it possible to change the values of a column depending on the existing values?

Comment: Check answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27699111/with-laravel-migration-how-to-change-data-type-of-a-column-and-update-its-exist/27699112)

Comment: Thanks @Arman that’s exactly what I was looking for. I wonder why it didn’t show up during my search… I’m closing this question.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options

1. you can create new table and move your data to there as you wanted to
2. you can create state_values table and than give a relationship with existing table. For this relationship you need to use belongsTo key.

Comment: Thank you, but Armans answer was actually the one I was looking for.